# Responsive css masonry style layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, masonry

Is there a way i can achieve this responsive layout. I've approached it from a number of different angles, using masonry, packery and just using CSS.

[3 column stacked grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USBjE.png)

Thus far i have not been able to get the grid pixel perfect, some guidence would be hugely appreciated.

This is the most recent markup i'm experimenting with, i don't intent on adding additional blocks, i just need to find a way to make these pixel perfect.

```
<style type="text/css">

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;  
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.A {
    width: calc(66% - 20px);
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.B {
    width: calc(33% - 20px);
    background-color: orange;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.C {    
    width: calc(33% - 20px);
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.last { margin: right 0;}
.third {width: 33%;}
.two-thirds {width: 66%;}
.row {margin-bottom:20px;}
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="block A">A</div>
    <div class="block B last"> last">B</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="block B">B</div>
    <div class="block A last">A</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="two-thirds">
        <div class="block C">C</div>
        <div class="block C">C</div>
        <div class="block A last">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="third">
        <div class="block B">B</div>
        <div class="block C">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, there really isn''t ...without deciding how you want the rows and columnd to work **before** you lay them out. There is a reason why javascript solutions still exist,

Comment: That's not to say you can't build this, probably with flexboxes, but not as a grid system...no.